# How to install Tensorflow and Keras library on windows 10 home edition?

Tags: python, keras

Please guide me the steps and source to install Tensorflow and keras on Windows 10 home edition using python (pip)?

Comment: I know it's not the answer to your question but I use windows 10 in my work place I recommend installing Anaconda and using it insted of pip. There are plenty links for installing Tensorflow in windows using it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following at command prompt:

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow

pip install --upgrade keras
```

Also, refer the following link for more detail:

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

Answer (score 0):

I had many issues installing tensorflow and keras by using: pip install...
I would suggest to you Anaconda.navigator. Although It is slower than Anaconda prompt, it helped me to understand the installation process. It worked for me.

First, I uninstalled old versions of Python and Anaconda and Installed Anaconda for Python 3.7 from [here](https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/) (Anaconda3-2019.10-Windows-x86_64.exe) (At this time Tensorflow and keras do not support Python 3.8).

In the Anaconda.Navigator I went to "environments" select "create" (create new environment) and name it. Then, on your new environment select what ever you want to install (tensorflow, tensorflow-gpu, keras, keras-gpu). Make sure that Python lower than 3.8 is on your new environment. This [video1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2QZTTuq1Xyg) and [video2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yFrc2SCdW7w) may help you.
I hope you solve your problem.